# transposing an open Bm chord with the capo on the 5th fret

Tags: rhythm

What would the open Bm chord in G progression be when transposed with capo on the 5th fret?

Comment: It's not clear whether you're *transposing* (changing key of G to key of C) or *re-voicing the chord* (changing Bm from Am shape at fret 2 to Em shape at fret 7).

Answer (score 1):

Bm moved 5 frets up would result in Em.

Comment: What would the Em on the 5th be a BM then?

Comment: No, it's always +5 semitones. Em + 5 semitones results in Am.

Answer (score 0):

An *open* Bm? Open chords are so-called because they contain notes played on open strings, like an open G or open C which are probably in the same piece.

On to the answer. When any chord shape is moved along the fingerboard, its name will change. By moving the capo 5 frets, the chord will be called Em, as it's a perfect 5th higher. Another way to look at it is Bm is the iii of G. But now, we're in C major, so that chord will be the iii of C, which is Em.